# I'm trying to use MediaTypeUtils.getMediaTypeForFileName

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, media-type

sorry to bother you all but I have a simple issue which is obsessing me, I'm trying to use `MediaTypeUtils.getMediaTypeForFileName` but I can't manage to find any dependency, I only get "cannot be resolved" for a project trying to get a .zip file on a external API. I don't think the rest of the code matters a lot since it's definitely not working yet.

Please give me any tip or advice as I'm quite the beginner. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You forgot to mention versions of Spring /Spring boot

Comment: @4EACH Sorry about that, I'm using spring boot 2.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found out that it was just an import from another java file that I didn't notice on the project, that's why I couldn't find any dependancy. I had trouble with it because it was some random tutorial on the web and it wasn't much documented.

Sorry about that.